# Geocoder failure - sometimes returning null array

Tags: android, geocoding

I'm facing a problem, that I don't know how to solve. I have an app, that uses built-in android geocoder. The code is simple - I'm getting the address and coordinates to display them on the map. On the emulator, it runs just fine, but on all the real devices the app crashes, trying to get some addresses(geocoder returns null array).
Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doinbackground SetRightMapDisplayAddress started");
        long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("The thread id is: %d", threadId));
        context = getActivity();

        String placeName = params[0];
        List<Address> addressList = downloadData.findAddressesByName(context, placeName);
        int returnedAddresses = addressList.size();

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(returnedAddresses));
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(startTime-endTime));
        Log.d(TAG, "doinbackground SetRightMapDisplayAddress ended");
        return addressList;
    }
```

The exception (it points to this  line :

```
int returnedAddresses = addressList.size();
```

):

```
07-01 15:41:58.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9158): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.shop.pagerFragments.TorgCentrMapFragment$SetRightMapDisplayAddress.doInBackground(TorgCentrMapFragment.java:349)
        at com.shop.pagerFragments.TorgCentrMapFragment$SetRightMapDisplayAddress.doInBackground(TorgCentrMapFragment.java:337)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 4 more
```

I've read a lot here, but I wasn't able to find the solution. Maybe there is a web api, that can grab the same address list?? Maybe there are some services, that are hidden and not available on the device (maybe I need to populate the alert and let the user turn on some services) ??
P.S. The location services were running on all the devices. Please, I need your help badly, guys.

Comment: what device are you using to test this, I have experienced that some devices don't have inbuilt geocoder like SonyEricsson Neo

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been reported before to google where the Geocoder doesn't work with few devices and turn around suggested was to restart the phone.

Also you can use the reverse Geocoding you will find all you need here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: phone restart is not helping. Thanks, for the answer.